# How to calculate acceleration from speed variable

Tags: r

I have the following data & i need to calculate the acceleration (change in velocity per unit time). Please note that I have some missing time stamps in the middle so How can I calculate
acceleration.. I tried the following code but need to know if this approach is correct.

What I had done is calculate the speed difference & also time difference...& finally removed timediff which are above 1 second & that gives me automatically acceleration per second.

Sample data:

```
vehicle ID                                Timestamp                Speed
1 ID12                             2018-04-03 03:03:13          30.85253
2 ID12                             2018-04-03 03:03:14          33.37131
3 ID12                             2018-04-03 03:03:24          35.31485
4 ID12                             2018-04-03 03:03:25          36.86404
5 ID12                             2018-04-03 03:03:26          37.73222
6 ID12                             2018-04-03 03:03:30          37.08222
.                                       .           .
.                                       .           .

tempdata<-Df%>%

  group_by(vehcile ID) %>%

  mutate(Speed_Diff = Speed - lead(Speed,1))



tempdata<-as.data.frame(tempdata)


tempdata <- na.omit(tempdata)

j<-tempdata$Timestamp

timediff<-difftime(j[1:(length(j)-1)],j[2:length(j)])


timediff<-as.data.frame(timediff)

timediff[nrow(timediff)+1,] <- NA 

########make rows of this dataframe & Output dataframe consistent by adding a 

NA row###


tempdata2<-cbind(tempdata,timediff)

tempdata2 <- na.omittempdata2

tempdata2$timediff<-as.numeric(abstempdata2$timediff))


Finaldataframe<- tempdata2tempdata2$timediff==1,]
```

Comment: After grouping try something like `diff(Df$Speed)/as.numeric(diff(Df$Timestamp))`.